# Change text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to change the text within a link on click from 'open' to 'close'.

```
<a href="#" id="clickMe"><span class="A open"></span>open</a>
```

But how do I change the label after I run an AJAX function on success?

```
success: function(){
   $("#clickMe").find("span").toggleClass("open close");
   // toggle label 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the actual TextNode contents as well by using `contents()` and the right index:

```
   var s = $("#clickMe").find("span").toggleClass("open close").attr('class'); 
    s = s.replace("A","").replace(" ",""); // get rid of the other class for the text to be used
   $("#clickMe").contents()[1].nodeValue = s;
```

or the same thing in a single line:

```
$("#clickMe").contents()[1].nodeValue = $("#clickMe").find("span").toggleClass("open close").attr('class').replace("A","").replace(" ","");
```

**edit**

If you wanna use some other texts than the class names, you could do it like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
   var s = $("#clickMe").find("span").toggleClass("open close").hasClass('open'); 
    if (s) s = "Open text";
    else s = "Closed text";

   $("#clickMe").contents()[1].nodeValue = s;

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ULsx4/13/

example (1): http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ULsx4/ & single line: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ULsx4/12/

Comment: Wow! this is really cool, but I'm afraid I used a poor example. What is my label text is not the same as the class name?

Comment: @santa no problem, edited my answer and an example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/ULsx4/13/

Comment: I think we have a winner! This is a very elegant solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the text use could use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$("#clickMe").html("<span class=\"close\"></span>close");
```

And if you want to leave the `span` untouched:

```
$('#clickMe').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith('close');
```

Comment: It looks like the text that needs to change is not inside the `span`, just inside the `a` element.

Comment: @James Allardice, you are perfectly correct. Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Yes, the span contains only an icon. Text is withing a <a href> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`$("#clickMe span").text("my text")`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickMe').contents().filter(function() {   
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).get(0).nodeValue = 'Hello';
```